# Turn `func(in: Source[A]) : Source[B]` into a `Flow[A, B]`

Tags: akka-stream, akka-grpc

I am using akka-grpc to generate client bindings. They usually have the form of

`func[A, B](in: Source[A]) : Source[B]`,

i.e. they consume a `Source[A]` and offer a `Source[B]`.

Now, I want to turn `func` into a `Flow[A, B]` to use them with akka-stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
  def SourceProcessor[In, Out](f : Source[In, NotUsed] => Source[Out, NotUsed]): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] = 
    Flow[In].prefixAndTail(0).flatMapConcat { case (Nil, in) => f(in) }
```

It uses `prefixAndTail` to highjack the underyling `Source`.